# How can I use a Chef resource within a library module? (Or should I...)?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to better organize some Chef recipes by collecting common Ruby logic in a helper library.  I've seen examples declaring a class in the library (i.e. class Chef::Recipe::MyHelper) with a few reusable methods inside.  I've also seen examples using a module in a similar manner.  In my case I wanted to use a resource inside a few of these methods.

For example, say I want to provide a helper method that takes an array of service names and loops through stopping each one using the service resource.  I want to cleanup the recipe files as much as possible and keep some of that logic out by just calling a "stopServices(serviceList)" method.

If I define the helper library like:

```
class Chef::Recipe::MyHelper
  def self.stopServices(serviceList)
    serviceList.each do |svc|
      service "#{svc}" do
        action :stop
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my recipe I use:

```
MyHelper.stopServices(serviceList)
```

I get the error: "undefined method 'service' for Chef::Recipe::MyHelper:Class".

Is there an easy way to be able to use resources in a library like that?  (Whether the library contains MyHelper as a class or module)?  Is this just a bad practice that I'm violating?  I've done a lot of searching and can't find anybody asking something similar which leads me to believe I'm probably doing something I shouldn't so any alternative suggestions would be much appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Libraries](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_libraries.html) are a way to abstract complex Ruby code away from a cookbook recipe.

To group resources (Chef DSL code) you should use either

- [Definitions](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_definitions.html) (simplest option) which you can use like a regular Chef resource in your recipes; or
- [LWRPs](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/lwrps_custom.html) which are more complex but support different actions (think `service` resources that you can `:start`, `:stop`, `:restart`, etc; or `package` resources that you can `:install`, `:upgrade`, `:remove`, etc).

---

**Update**

A definition that would solve your example problem:

```
# cookbooks/common/definitions/common_stop_services.rb
define :common_stop_services, :services => [] do
  params[:services].each do |svc|
    service svc do
      action :stop
    end
  end
end
```

then use it like this:

```
# my_cookbook/recipes/my_recipe.rb
common_stop_services "my_recipe_services" do
  services [ 'svc1', 'svc2' ]
end
```

*Obs: It's probably worth it asking yourself if you really want to wrap multiple service stoppage in a common method. Usually a service action is notified by some other resource (classic example is a configuration file change notifying the reconfigured service to restart, but other patterns apply as well).*

*Obs2: CamelCase is only used for `Classes` and `Modules` in Ruby code. I recommend reading the [style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby).*

*Obs3: Even if you were to implement that code in a library, you probably don't want to use a `Class`. You're never going to instantiate `MyHelper`, so what you want is a `Module` instead.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think LWRPs are the way for me to go long term.  In the short term I'm still wondering if what I'm trying to do is possible.  To cleanup the recipes I moved a lot of these methods into a library file in a "common" cookbook and made the other cookbooks that needed them depend on that cookbook.  I didn't bother to wrap the methods in a class or module and it works fine written exactly as above just without the class line (and the "self.") but still calling the resource from the method in the library.

Comment: I wanted to wrap it in a class as a best practice to avoid polluting the default namespace and to make it more obvious where the method is coming from in the other recipes by having a "MyHelper.stopServices" instead of just "stopServices".  It seems the only issue is that when I wrap it in a class it assumes the service resource is part of that class.  So it seems like a simple namespace issue but nothing I've tried fixes that.  Is there some way I can fully qualify the resource name or otherwise specify what it is in order to use it in this manner?

Comment: Again, you're subverting the usage of libraries to do Chef DSL calls. You're also not making it any clearer by declaring a class whose name doesn't give you a clue about where it comes from (perhaps `Common` would be a better name, as it would match its cookbook's?). I have edited my answer to demonstrate how you could implement a definition for your problem. I've also added a few observations that could help you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the example.  I obviously have a lot to learn but that definition helps.  I'll look into making better use of LWRPs and notify service resources that need to stop / start.